# How disable a specific validation message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several model validation, but at one specific I want to validate but not return its message on error.

I tried:

```
validates :birth_text, presence: true, message: false
```

Or

```
validates :birth_text, presence: true, message: ''
```

Error:

```
in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator' (ArgumentError)
```

I want to do this, because I will validate on another field and it is returning duplicates error message.

Comment: do you add message validator

Comment: I don't, it is taken the default: #{field} is not valid. @RajarshiDas

Comment: look at my post may be it will make a help for you @Ricardo